# which program will be started

Tags: bash

I have copied the `id` program from `/usr/bin/` directory to my `home` directory. I don't know which one will be started after execution `id` command in directory where I copied this program.

Bash will search for the program in  `PATH` variable or execute it form the directory?

Is  there any way to check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `type id` or `command -v id` to see how `bash` will interpret `id` as a command.  For me I see:

```
$ type id
id is /usr/bin/id
$ command -v id
/usr/bin/id
```

And yes, `bash` will search `$PATH`, although once it has found it once it will remember that location so it doesn't have to search every time.  This can cause problems if you move it after having run it previously.  You can see this with the `hash` command `hash id` to see if such an entry currently exists.

Answer (score 0):

The shell will always search the directories listed in your `PATH` variable, in order, until a matching command is found.

You may see what `id` it picks up by using the command

```
command -v id
```

Note that if you are moving binaries around (you shouldn't do that), you may have to run `hash -r` to reset `bash`'s cashed list of remembered locations of utilities.